# directx basic capability testing

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, directx, managed-directx

I have a managed directx 9.0c application that fails to run on some low spec machines (ones without graphics card).

I am wondering if anyone has any suggestions with regards to the minimum directx caps to test for so that I can catch a potential failure before trying to run the application.

The directx application only displays a few meshes and a couple of textures and nothing too intensive.

I currently check for SupportsHardwareTransformAndLight and enable HardwareVertexprocessing if it does and enable SoftwareVertexProcessing if it does not.  Just wondering what else I should look for?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it fails when initializing DirectX 9.0c itself?

Several things can happen:

- DX9.0c might not be installed on the machine. It is included in Windows XP SP2 and later, but on earlier versions of Windows, the runtime must be installed manually.
- Hardware acceleration might not be available. Either the user does not have *any* graphics drivers installed, or has explicitly disabled hardware acceleration in driver settings.

Based on data we have, the above situations are true for about 3% of the "casual user" space ([2009 Q1 data](http://unity3d.com/webplayer/hwstats/pages/web-2009Q1-shader.html)).

Other than that, maybe your application itself uses some features without checking whether they are supported by the graphics card.

Comment: thank you for your answer.  I am testing on a Virtual Machine (Microsoft Virtual PC) and it uses the standard display drivers (no installed driver). The link to the survey was very interesting, thanks.

Comment: Last time I checked, Virtual PC did not have hardware acceleration for D3D9. So in majority of cases it should fail to initialize there.